# How to detect if a text is Person, Organization, or other entity using Spacy?

Tags: csv, machine-learning, spacy, text-recognition

I have a csv records of sales, each record has column customer name. This column is a combination of persons name and organization name. How can I use spacy to detect if a this column is a person or organization?

Comment: Have you done any research? Within 3 clicks on the spacy website, they show you how to extract entities from text...

Comment: @ValentinCalomme yes i did some research. thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 'Named Entity Recognition' task. Spacy has a pretty good [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#101):

```py
doc = nlp(u'Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion')

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)

Apple 0 5 ORG
```